# in which directory should Firefox be compiled?

Tags: rhel, compiling, firefox

I want to compile Firefox browser in RHEL.
I found two directories one is `/root/.mozilla/firefox` and other one is `/usr/lib64/firefox`.
Which directory is the one where Firefox should be compiled?

Answer (score 2):

None of them `.mozilla` will contains your firefox settings and cutomizations and `/usr/lib`or `/usr/lib64` contains library usefull to run your firefox installation.
You should
 - create a folder inside your home folder name `firefox_compile` for example
 - download the sources in this directory
 - install all the libraries and compilers you need
 - do a `./configure` `./mach` ... whatever documentation told you to.
 - and then `make install` which will probably propagate firefox in the folder `/usr/sbin` or `/usr/bin` or any directory you will have setup during the `./configure`

**Notes:**
 - You should avoid to compile things as `root` it's usually not a good idea because it can set the stickybit of your app which is not good.
 - You can see documentation on how to [compile firefox here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Simple_Firefox_build). you should use the same step as Fedora distribution.
 - Firefox does use `./mach` and not `make`

Good luck

Comment: `make install` into a system with a package manager is the apex of evil. If you ever need to uninstall or upgrade the package, it becomes very difficult to clean out all the old pieces. And you've now got files on the system which the package manager isn't aware of which can cause all sorts of other issues.

Comment: @Patrick yes but if you do want to compile it, it's your choice :D

Comment: @Kiwy Thank you very much. i have  a doubt that when  i installed rhel 6.3, there will be some inbuilt firefox. if i want to make changes(like disable menu items and disable file protocol from url)  in which directory i have to do. is it /.mozilla/firefox or /usr/lib64/firefox. otherwise i have to uninstall inbuilt firefox and i have to follow steps what you told?

Comment: @subbarao you do not abandonned this old project :D good luck, though yes if you have a lib/firefox it probably mean a firefox package is already install. to compile firefox, please refer to (developer.mozilla.org), they have all you need in terms of material.